# Mock SOQL in Test class

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, community, ideas

Is there a way to mock SOQL in test class in salesforce.
Like we have mockito in java.

Say for example:
I have a batchable job which has the following soql in its execute method:
`[SELECT T***,***,**** FROM Territory__c WHERE *** IN: ***.keySet()]`

Normally I couldn't figure out why it cannot query any record. So I thought of that similar mockito framework could help here.
For eg: `when ([SELECT T***,***,**** FROM Territory__c WHERE *** IN: ***.keySet()]).thenReturn(new List<Territory2>)`
Which would greatly help in test coverage. Is there a mock framework available?

Comment: Similar to any unit test in Salesforce, you need to insert your prerequisite data for the test and then call `startTest()` and then kick off your batch. Have you reviewed the documentation about how to test a batch? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: You can try to use apex stub feature -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm

Comment: @kurunve I don't get stubs. In the documentation the stub is not testing the functionality of the helper it just returns a static value. To me that is completely against what testing is supposed to do. Same as a smoke test as it will never fail. Maybe I just don't understand it....or is the point to take the helper out of the equation when testing the main class and still test the helper separately  later? That makes more sense

Comment: @Eric stubs can be really useful if you can not generate proper test setup for complex method, which calls dozens of other ones. To check one concrete edge case (aka invalid data), you stub one of that methods. And you are right, stub methods are not supposed to test methods, which are stubbed, but to test another methods, where those are used in easier way

Answer (score 1):

You can insert records from Test methods and they exist in Salesforce only while your test method is executing.

For testing a batch job, you need to wrap the call to `Database.executeBatch` method inside `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` methods.

E.g.

```
Test.startTest();
YourBatchClass batch = new YourBatchClass();
Database.executeBatch(batch, 1);
Test.stopTest();
```

Wrapping `executeBatch` method inside start and stop test methods ensures the batch job runs immediately and results are available before the test method ends.

Also, one more important point while testing batch jobs is that the number of records returned by `start` method when test method is executing should result in only one batch execution of your batch class.

> When testing your batch Apex, you can test only one execution of the execute method. Use the scope parameter of the executeBatch method to limit the number of records passed into the execute method to ensure that you aren’t running into governor limits.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have this written, but the problem is even if i have @Testsetup data, some data is missing because of which I cannot proceed further and cannot complete the test coverage.

Comment: Are you still stuck with this? Is it possible for you to append your test class to your question?